# Visual Studio 2010 SDK, Get Caret Column

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Pretty self explanatory, but I'm try to find how far out from left the caret is.
Currently I have the following line

```
var caret = m_doc.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
return doc.GetTextViewLineContainingBufferPosition(caret).Start.Difference(caret);
```

where doc is a IWpfTextView.

The problem is if you have a tab it counts the tab as one instead of how many spaces make up the tab.

EXAMPLE - | represents where the cursor is, \t a tab with a size of 4, charNo is what my code currently returns, col is what I want:

```
|var a  //col:0 charNo:0
\t|var  //col:4 charNo:1
 \t|var //col:4 charNo:2
 \tv|ar //col:5 charNo:3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `.Left` instead of `.Start`?  That returns the current position from the Left of the coordinate plane regardless of tabs.

Comment: Left returns a double which I presume is the number of pixels from the left.

Comment: exactly. msdn says: Distances in the text rendering coordinate system correspond to logical pixels. If the text rendering surface is displayed without any scaling transform, then 1 unit in the text rendering coordinate system corresponds to one pixel on the display. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.formatting.iwpftextviewline.aspx

Comment: but I'm not after the pixel location, I'm after the column, as my example shows, I'm after how many characters in you are in, but with treating a tab as the number of spaces it represents.

Comment: oh ic...  you changed your question. you should note that in some way when you do it.